# Help using noun + までも without ない; and とってあく

Tags: grammar, translation, words

I'm reading a manga about a person who becomes a bodyguard for the head of a Yakuza syndicate, due to various reasons including debt. There's a part where the body guard is being threatened after being kidnapped as bait, the real target being the kumicho. The bodyguard starts laughing after the kidnappers say that they are the body guard that the kumicho is most attached to/fond of, and so he will be disturbed and horrified from the bodyguard's death.

Then the bodyguard says:
「残念だったね　僕は彼にとってあく　*までも*　ただのボデぃガード．．．」

I know how to use までも with verb-ない form and I know までもない but I'm not sure what it means without ない. I tried to search for how to use it on grammar sites but everything had ない.

On a side note, I believe とってあく in this context (since there is no kanji to clarify) may mean "scum (that has been skimmed off the top of something)" but I am not sure. I looked in several dictionaries and also searched for related idioms, but was unable to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word separation is incorrect. It should read:

> 僕は　彼にとって　あくまでも　ただの　ボディガード．．．

あくまでも means “nothing more than that” in this context.
So the sentence should be:

> To him, I’m just a body guard - nothing more than that.

Note that あくまでも has some other meanings, like “persistently” etc.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much! Do you know what とって means in this context then? Or perhaps the infinitive form of the verb? Without any kanji (even if it's kanji Im not familiar with) I found it rather confusing...

Comment: @EmilyOkita http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6

Comment: It is not a grammar form. It means “to him” or “for him”: I am just a body guard *for him*.  Another example would be あなたは私にとって大切な人です。”You are a very important person to me”.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now, thank you!

Comment: @EmilyOkita I am glad I can help. Please mark my answer as the accepted answer if that helps you. Thank you.

Comment: It's often helpful to think of Xにとって as "from X's perspective".